# Android save Canvas to SD

Tags: android, android-canvas

I was create image on the canvas using colorfilter

This my code

```
     int color = mPaint.getColor();
     f = new LightingColorFilter(color, 1);
     mPaint.setColorFilter(f);


     myBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon10);
     canvas.drawBitmap(myBmp, 20, 20, mPaint);
     canvas.save();
     canvas.restore();`
```

and then,I want to save it to sdcard

```
            OutputStream outStream = null;
            File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "er.PNG");
            try {
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            myBmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, outStream);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();

            Toast.makeText(Draw.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(Draw.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(Draw.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
```

It's Work But have Problem,My picture on sd is old picture(not filter)

can I fix this problem??,Thank

Comment: Just delete the old one and save the new one, or, preferably, just rename the new one to filename + "_filtered.png" perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

You need draw into Bitmap. Try below:

```
 int color = mPaint.getColor();
 f = new LightingColorFilter(color, 1);
 mPaint.setColorFilter(f);
 Bitmap outBitmap = Bitmap.Create(myBmp.getWidth(),myBmp.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
 Canvas canvas = new Canvas(outBitmap);
 canvas.drawBitmap(myBmp,20,20,mPaint);
```

And than you can "save it"(outBitmap) to SD card.
If you're open Bitmap with BitmapFactory you'd get immutable bitmap, and can't draw on it. 
That's why you need to create temp. Bitmap, connect Canvas for draw, Drawing and can saving.